# Embedded spring cloud config server with jdbc backend in my springboot application

Tags: spring-cloud-config

We have a requirement to read the application properties from the Database. To achieve this I am trying to use spring cloud. I am trying to embed the config server in a spring boot application with JDBC backend so that the application can configure itself by reading properties from the DB. But I am unable to configure bootstrap.properties file. I am getting the following error:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a URI for the git repository.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:253)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
```

My bootstrap.properties file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh

spring.application.name=demo
spring.cloud.config.label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true

spring.profiles.active=jdbc
```

The question is why do we need to configure a git repository when we are using JDBC as a backend to load all the properties?
And also how can I configure this get my JDBC config work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Girish, did you manage to solve your issue? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Based on the documentation you should always use bootstrap=true with composite repository. So this is the first problem. But If you change it to composite with jdbc then there is another problem that jdbcEnvironmentRepositoryFactory is not autoconfigured because JdbcTemplate is not autoconfigured in bootstrap application context. Discussed also here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1454

Answer (score 0):

in order to get jdbc working you need the following properties in application.yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
        server:
            jdbc:
                sql: SELECT KEY, VALUE FROM CONFIG_PROPERTIES WHERE APPLICATION=? AND PROFILE=? AND LABEL=?
            bootstrap: true
datasource:
    url: datasourcehere
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
profiles:
    active: jdbc
```

And Application.java as following:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Import({ JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class })
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

good luck

Comment: What's the purpose of @RestController and @Import({ JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class }) here ? Why Application class should be RestController and why you are importing JdbcEnvironmentRepository as configuration if it's not a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed **META-INF/spring.factories** with such content to datasource && jdbcTemplate run during initialising spring-cloud-config context (**order of classes is important**)

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my application set up as an embedded Cloud Config Server without endpoint and JDBC backend.

I hope to help others by posting my working configuration:

in **pom.xml** I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

For the spring dependencies I use the 2.2.2.RELEASE version.
As suggested by the other answer, in order to have Spring autoconfigure the JDBCRepository, I had to add **src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories** containing:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration
```

Following Spring's documentation for the embedded Cloud Config server with no endpoint I added **src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml** containing:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapplication
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        composite:
        - 
          type: jdbc
          sql: SELECT KEY, VALUE from PROPERTIES where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and LABEL=?
          order: 1
      name: myapplication
  datasource:
    url: mydatabaseurl
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    username: mydatabaseusername
    password: mydatabasepassword
```

I am not sure yet if I need to define twice "myapplication". In the PROPERTIES table I have rows with APPLICATION = myapplication, PROFILE = composite and LABEL = master.

Instead of the Spring Boot Application, I defined a class implementing SpringBootServletInitializer, and I did not use any of "@SpringBootApplication", "@EnableConfigServer", "@EnableDiscoveryClient" or "@Import({ JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class })".

You may need to set allow-bean-definition-overriding=true in **src/main/resources/application.properties**.

I hope this helps somebody setting up Cloud Config as embedded server without endpoint.